# How to render filter checkboxes in ReactJS with JSON data?

Tags: reactjs

I have some search results from AJAX call returned to me in JSON. How would I go about creating checkbox filters in ReactJS? It's so easy in AngularJS but not sure how that would work in ReactJS.

For example, what if I automatically want checkbox filters like:

```
Supplier
[] Ewaste (2)
[] Mike's Cleaning (1)

Preferred
[] Green Business (1)
[] Minority Business (1)

Ratings
[] 1 (1)
[] 2 (1)
[] 3 (1)
```

And my JSON was like

```
{
  "searchresults": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ABC Cleanup",
      "supplier": "EWaste",
      "type": "invoice",
      "status": "open",
      "status_message": "Open",
      "date": "2015/08/28",
      "totalAmount": null,
      "currency": "USD",
      "ratings": 1,
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Teaching BCD",
      "supplier": "EWaste",
      "type": "request",
      "preferred":"Green Business",
      "status": null,
      "status_message": null,
      "date": "2015/08/28",
      "totalAmount": null,
      "currency": "USD",
      "ratings": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Mike's Pizza",
      "supplier": "Mike's Cleaning",
      "type": "invoice",
      "preferred":"Minority Business",
      "status": "open",
      "status_message": null,
      "date": "2015/08/31",
      "totalAmount": "10,201",
      "currency": "USD",
      "ratings": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all up to you.

I guess that you are using the json data to render a `table` component, and you want to add `filters` which are some checkboxes as filters for the `table`.

If you are doing so, you should make the json data as the state of the `table` component, calling `setState` or `getInitialState` to do this work. Then you should using the `state` of the table to render the rows.

Then you should bind a event handler for all the checkbox, in the handler you should determine what the json data should be for the filtered table, and then call `setState` with that new json data to rerend the table.